# When I run a lot of http requests in parallel, I get "no such protocol name: tcp"

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

The code

```
mapConcurrently httpLBS requests
```

throws

```
ConnectionFailure Network.BSD.getProtocolByName: does not exist (no such protocol name: tcp))
```

after about 1k requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requests are all run in parallel and make the process run out of file descriptors. Use

```
import ClassyPrelude

traverseThrottled :: (MonadMask m, MonadBaseControl IO m, Forall (Pure m), Traversable t) => Int -> (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
traverseThrottled concLevel action taskContainer = do
    sem <- newQSem concLevel
    let throttledAction = bracket_ (waitQSem sem) (signalQSem sem) . action
    mapConcurrently throttledAction taskContainer
```

(adjust imports if you don't use `ClassyPrelude`)

Make sure your equivalent of `httpLBS` consumes the request if you use a streaming alternative. And that your `b` is strict in all fields.